# Can't access a scope property from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to read an attribute from a directive but when when i want to accees to it (scope.b) it gives me always true and it's actualut an array .

This is the directive definition :

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('main')
    .directive('specialities', show_specialities);

function show_specialities() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            b: '=specialities'
        },
        link: linker
    }
    function linker(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope);
        console.log(scope.b); // it prints true
    }
}
})();
```

This is the directive :

```
    <specialities specialities="courses.specialities"></specialities>
```

A screen shot from the console :

[image]

Comment: Is the variable `b` being used by something else in Angular, where it's being set to `true`? Have you tried changing the variable name to something more descriptive and unique?

Comment: I wrote a codepen and your code seems to work: http://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/qNZxVP?editors=1012

Comment: Thanks for your answer normaly it has the name specialities and i changed to b, but even if it's true why the console gives an array as a value of the attribute b.